# AngularJS: How do you pass in element id with multiple scope parameters in the id string?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have elements in an `ng-repeat` loop with multiple other loops on the page. The loops look like:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in MyArray"> ....
```

For this reason the elements are all classified with id's such as:

```
<input id="{{a.Id}}{{a.Name}}{{a.Value}}"....
```

In the same `input` variable, I have an `ng-class` parameter that calls a function that passes the id to the js.

How would I go about passing in such an id?

I know that theoretically, it would be passed in like this:

```
ng-class="myfunction({{a.Id}}{{a.Name}}{{a.Value}})"
```

If the Id was 15, Name was "Broom" and Value was 5, how can I pass into the `ng=class` function such a variable:

```
ng-class=myfunction("15Broom5")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same input field just change as this:

```
<input type="text" id="{'a':$scope.Id,'a'.$scope.Name,'a':$scope.Value}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a expression & concatenate the values.

```
 ng-class="myfunction(a.Id + a.Name + a.Value)"
```

Comment: What if all three variables are numbers, wouldn't it add them all together and pass in a sum value?